# How to upgrade sharepoint foundation 2010 to use SQL Server 2008 R2 (standard edition)?

Tags: windows, sharepoint-2010

We are developing asp.net application which uses SharePoint Foundation 2010 to store and retrieve documents. We have installed 'Standalone' SharePoint Foundation 2010 and used SQL Server 2008 R2 (Standard Edition) as a database for SharePoint Foundation 2010. This is wrong because we need to install SharePoint Foundation 2010 by using 'Server Farm' to use SQL Server 2008 R2 (Standard Edition) as a database. Now we want to know what should we need to do with existing installation to install SharePoint Foundation 2010 (Server Farm) that uses SQL Server 2008 R2 (Standard Edition) as a database. When we click on setup.exe of SharePoint Foundation 2010, it gives options - Repair and Remove. Should we need to remove SharePoint from this option and again install it in Server Farm type or we need to uninstall everying and install it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should reinstall Sharepoint 2010 in order to use SQL Server 2008 R2 as database server. Standalone installations simply don't support moving databases.

Comment: Yes, but does I need to format my system and re install all software again? or is there any other way ?

Comment: No, it's enough to uninstall Sharepoint only. I'd say back up the content databases if any, prior to uninstalling.

Comment: How should I uninstall it ? Should I click on setup.exe as it gives option - Repair and Remove ? From Remove option should I uninstall it?

Comment: Yes, indeed. After that, start it again, and select Farm and Complete install.